# How can I modify a variable in a .conf file in another Yocto layer from my custom layer?

Tags: yocto

Using Yocto I am bitbaking a custom image based on an image in another layer (let's call it layer A).
To pull in the packages I need, I must change a .conf file variable in the layer A.
The conf file is located in meta-layer-A/conf/distro.conf
The variable I want to change is

```
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/docker,
```

which is set to "docker-ce".
I need to change it to "docker-moby" so that I can build recipe docker-moby.

I would prefer to make changes only in my custom layer, and not in any other layer incl. layer A.
How can that be done?

When I manually change

```
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/docker = "docker-ce"
```

to

```
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/docker = "docker-moby"
```

in the original layer i can build docker-moby.

I have tried overriding the variable by setting it in my local.conf in my build folder. (as described here [How to override a .conf file in Yocto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58642084/how-to-override-a-conf-file-in-yocto))

```
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/docker = "docker-moby"
```

That does not override it.

When I try 'bitbake docker-moby', or even 'bitbake -e docker-moby', I just get

```
Loading cache: 100% |#######################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00Loaded 3848 entries from dependency cache.
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'docker-moby'
docker-moby was skipped: PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/docker set to docker-ce, not docker-moby
docker-moby was skipped: PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/docker set to docker-ce, not docker-moby
```

This is true even if I comment out setting the variable at all in the distro.conf file.

I get this from 'bitbake-layers show-recipes | grep docker-moby'

```
docker-moby:
  meta-layer-A unknown (skipped: PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/docker set to docker-ce, not docker-moby)
  meta-virtualization  unknown (skipped: PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/docker set to docker-ce, not docker-moby)
```

edit:
I managed to get the evaluation order of conf files. Looks like local.conf is not the last conf file to be evaluated:

```
# $PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/docker [4 operations]
#   set? /home/jugge/projects/tc_yocto_temp/build/conf/../../layers/meta-virtualization/conf/layer.conf:37
#     "docker-ce"
#   _remove /home/jugge/projects/tc_yocto_temp/build/conf/local.conf:47
#     "docker-ce"
#   postdot /home/jugge/projects/tc_yocto_temp/build/conf/local.conf:48
#     "docker-moby"
#   set /home/jugge/projects/tc_yocto_temp/build/conf/../../layers/meta-layer-A/conf/distro/include/original.inc:27
#     "docker-ce"
# pre-expansion value:
#   "docker-ce"
```

edit2:
I infused a .conf file that gets infused and evaluated after original.inc. I can see that it is finally set to the value "docker-moby", but still I get the error that nothing is providing docker-moby.

```
# $PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/docker [3 operations]
#   set? /home/jugge/projects/tc_yocto_temp/build/conf/../../layers/meta-virtualization/conf/layer.conf:37
#     "docker-ce"
#   set /home/jugge/projects/tc_yocto_temp/build/conf/../../layers/meta-layer-A/conf/distro/include/original.inc:28
#     "docker-moby"
#   set /home/jugge/projects/tc_yocto_temp/build/conf/../../layers/meta-custom/conf/custom.conf:4
#     "docker-moby"
# pre-expansion value:
#   "docker-moby"
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/docker="docker-moby"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I finally used was to create my own distribution, and a corresponding configuration file in meta-custom/conf/distro which included the line `PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/docker="docker-moby"`.
That way the original meta-layer-A conf file was never read and no PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/docker was set prior to my distro conf setting it (except the soft setting from meta-virtualization).